# ProcessIdToSessionId returns wrong session ID

Tags: c#, c++, session

I have a C# service the is a web socket server. When a web socket connection is received I get the process ID of the connecting application (Chrome) from the socket and then I get the session ID of this process. 
Getting the process ID and session ID is done in a C++ dll that is loaded by the C# service.

Looking at the Processes tab in task manager I see an entry for chrome.exe with a PID of 5640 and a Session ID of 45.

in the C++ dll I am using GetExtendedTcpTable() to find the process ID from the port. This seems to work fine as I retrieve the correct process ID (in my example PID is 5640).
However when I use this process ID in ProcessIdToSessionId() the session ID returned is 44!

Why would ProcessIdToSessionId() return the wrong session ID?

OS is Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered the problem!
I used a wrapper function to call ProcessIdToSessionId(). This function was written for an application that was started in a session so it is optimised to only get the session ID once and saved it internally. The idea behind this was that it would be unnecessary to re-query the session ID from the current process as the session ID would never change. So when the function was called subsequently it did not call ProcessIdToSessionId() again but returned the stored value.

Of course re-using that function in a service that gets called from different sessions received the correct session ID on its first call but subsequent calls received the wrong session ID. Changing the wrapper function to force re-querying the session ID fixed the problem.